# Make selectable via trackball

Tags: android

I am display 4 ImageViews side by side on the header of a screen.

A part of the layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Buttons"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbg" android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/AddIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" android:src="@drawable/ic_add_normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/EditIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/AddIcon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/playIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" android:src="@drawable/ic_play_normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/EditIcon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I wanted the icons which is displayed at the header of the screen , to be selectable by the track ball of the mobile device & also should be focusable.